# Local-only domain forwarding to specific ports

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a laptop running linux mint 18 that is running an http server at port 80, chronograf at port 8888, home assistant at 8123, node-red 1880, and more. How can I setup either on my router (openwrt) or server itself some kind of port forwarding that homeassistant.server forwards to :8123 etc... or maybe if its better a subdomain type of idea ha. to :8123 so I dont need to remember all the different ports.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "you can't".  When there are some mechanisms in DNS for working with ports theses are highly protocol specific and not commonly used.

There are, however, workarounds.

The easiest would be to configure Apache as a reverse proxy. The HTTP protocol makes a connection on a given IP address and then specifies the domain.  Using the ProxyPass module and name based virtual hosts you can then proxy the request to another port.

The very messy alternative (which is, from a networking POV closer to what you are asking) would be to bind multiple IP addresses to your mint box (ie virtual interfaces) and then map each subdomain to a different IP address.  Once this is done you should be able to get decent software to bind to specific IPs on port 80, or failing which use iptables to redirect packets based on destination IP.